# jQuery Iterate through JSON Error

Tags: jquery, json

i have JSON data as follows

```
{"4":"Bangles","2":"Rings"}
```

I am trying to Iterate through the content to populate the Dropdown

```
$("#ProductProductTypeId").change(function(){
           var product_type_id = $(this).val();
           console.log(product_type_id);

           $.ajax({
              type: "get",
              url: "/alankruti/admin/product_categories/get_category/"+product_type_id,
              //data: country_id,
              success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var options = '';
                $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(value);
                     options += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
                     console.log(key + " " +value)
                });
              }
           });

     });
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a jSON Object from your data string using `jQuery.parseJSON`. Then you can iterate with `$.each`.

#### Sample

```
success:function(data){
    // create json object from data (string)
    jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON( data);
    console.log(data);
    var options = '';
    // iterate through json
    $.each(jsonObj , function (key,value) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
            options += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
            console.log(key + " " +value)
    });
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C9LQ3/1/)

#### References

- [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)
- [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: ahh. i m not doing JSONParse :(

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to know if you need further help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Taking your json:

```
{"4":"Bangles","2":"Rings"}
```

A simple `each()` loop like this works:

```
$.each(items, function(k, values) {
    console.log(k);
    console.log(values);
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/La5ne/1/)

---

Simply meaning all you had to do is

```
var options;
$.each(items, function(k, values) {
    options += "<option value='" + k + "'>" + values + "</option>";
});
// then append options to select...
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer by dknaack. Alternatively, try setting dataType: "json" in ajax. This ensures that in successHandler, the data object is a json object.

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
dataType : "json",
...
```